What does "maximally" breaks the symmetry in Galois theory mean as expressed by Alain Connes?
I have read the paper A view of mathematics by Alain Connes. If you read page 28 of this paper, you will read the following paragraph:

Abel and Galois analyzed the symmetries of functions of roots of
polynomial equations and Galois found that a function of the roots is
a "rational" expression iff it is invariant under a specific group $G$
of permutations naturally associated to the equation and to the notion
of what is considered as being "rational". Such a notion defines a
field $K$ containing the field $\Bbb Q$ of rational numbers always
present in characteristic zero. He first exhibits a rational function
$$V(a,b,\cdots,z)$$ of the $n$ distinct roots $(a,b,\cdots,z)$ of a
given equation of degree $n$, which affects $n!$ different values
under all permutations of the roots, i.e. which "maximally" breaks
the symmetry. He then shows that there are $n$ "rational" functions
$\alpha(V),\beta(V),\cdots$ of $V$ which give back the roots
$(a,b,\cdots,z)$. His group $G$ is obtained by decomposing in
irreducible factors over the field $K$ the polynomial (over $K$) of
degree $n!$ of which $V$ is a root. Using the above rational functions
$$\alpha(V_j), \beta(V_j), \cdots$$ applied to the other roots $V_j$
of the irreducible factor which admits $V$ as a root, yeilds the
desired group of permutations of the $n$ roots $(a,b,\cdots,z)$.

I have known that Galois theory is rather a theory that describes symmetry, but this paper explains that Galois theory is a theory that came about because it shattered symmetry which is contradictory, so I was confused.
So, I would appreciate it if you could explain in detail and in simple terms what is meant by "maximally" breaks the symmetry in this paper.

Let $V(a,b)=a+b+ab$ , when $n=2$
We can see that $V(a,b)=V(b,a)$ : It is Symmetric : We can get same "output" when "input" has Permutation.
Let $V(a,b,c)=a+b+c+ab+bc+ca+abc$ , when $n=3$
We can see that $V(a,b,c)=V(b,a,c)=V(b,c,a)$ : It is "highly" Symmetric : we can get same "output" when "input" has Permutation.
Let $V(a,b,c)=a+b+c+ab+abc$ , when $n=3$
We can see that $V(a,b,c)=V(b,a,c) \not =V(b,c,a)$ : It is not always Symmetric , though there are Cases where we can get same "output" when "input" has Permutation.
Let $V(a,b,c)=a+ab+abc$ , when $n=3$
We can see that $V(a,b,c) \not =V(b,a,c) \not =V(b,c,a)$ : It "maximally" breaks the Symmetry : there is no Case where we can get same "output" when "input" has Permutation.
Let $V(a,b,\cdots,z)$ which Galois exhibits , while ensuring that there is no Case where we can get same "output" when "input" has Permutation.
That is what "maximally" breaks the Symmetry here.
ADDENDUM :
I want to respond to OP Comment , though it is too long , hence including it here , while making it relevant to the Answer too.
OP : "[...] what powerful property does maximally breaking the symmetry have [...]"
I am not well into Galois Theory , I was only answering what the Paper Author was talking about.
Intuitively , the Author continues with stating that Galois used that function to extract the roots individually.
To me it is like this:
When we have $V(a,b)=a+b+ab$ and we want to know what the "output" value is , when $a,b$ are assigned the (unknown) Permutation over $\{10,20\}$ :
We will get $230$ , no matter the Permutation , hence we can not know which "input" was which.
When we have $V(a,b,)=a+ab+abc$ and we want to know what the value is , when $a,b,c$ are assigned the (unknown) Permutation over $\{10,20,30\}$ :
We might get $6210$ "output" , the Permutation must be $(a,b,c)=(10,20,30)$ hence we can know which "input" was which.
We might get $6220$ "output" , the Permutation must be $(a,b,c)=(20,10,30)$ hence we can know which "input" was which.
We might get $6620$ "output" , the Permutation must be $(a,b,c)=(20,30,10)$ hence we can know which "input" was which.
When the $V$ Galois exhibited "maximally" breaks the Symmetry , there are "input" $n!$ Permutations with $n!$ "output" values : It will enable knowing which (unknown) "input" Permutation was used where , when we are given the "output" $V$ value.
That Property is essential to extract the roots individually via Permutations using group/galois/field theory.

Hello, thank you very much for your sincere answer. However, I have one question. The reason why Galois was able to leave achievements on algebraic solutions using group theory and field theory, unlike senior mathematicians such as Ruffini and Lagrange, is because Galois maximally broke the symmetry in a historical perspective?
If this thinking is right, what powerful property does maximally breaking the symmetry have that led Galois to his mathematical success?

I have updated my intuitive answer with a little more thinking.

I know it was a bit of a hassle, but thank you so much for editing your answer. I understand now.
